# Erro código PHP Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\register.php on line 283

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Aparece os seguintes erros ao abrir a página da tabela:
Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\register.php on line 283

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\register.php on line 283

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\register.php on line 301

```
<div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
              <?php

                  $query = "SELECT * FROM register";
                  $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

             ?>


                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Nome</th>
                      <th>Protocolo</th>
                      <th>Data de abertura</th>
                      <th>Questionamento</th>
                      <th>Empresa</th>
                      <th>Observações</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)        
                    {
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                        {
                  ?>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['protocolo']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['data']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['questionamento']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['empresa']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php  echo $row['observacao']; ?></td>    

                      <?php } 
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "No Record Found";
                        }
                      ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: no código apresentado realmente não tem a variável $connection, onde ela estaria sendo chamada?

Comment: Em um arquivo externo de conexão ao banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Aparece os seguintes erros ao abrir a página da tabela: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\register.php on line 283

Está faltando os dados da conexão na variável $connection passada como parâmetro na função mysqli_query().

Tente atribuir o objeto de conexão antes de usar a variável "$connection".

Exemplo:

```
$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```